# GOLANG 64decode string illegal data, not sure why

Tags: string, go, decode

Fellow Gophers:

I'm stuck on something simple. I'm trying to convert decode a 64endoded string (OAUTH token to be exact).

I split the string, and put one of the parts of the split to be 64decoded, and I always find an illegal character. When I put the same value into any web based 64decoder it works.

I think that maybe there is a trailing null or something. Can anyone give me some advice. I put the code here: https://play.golang.org/p/cf-x6GgpEp

The exact error is: `illegal base64 data at input byte 408`

Below is the code as well, its pretty short:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    b64 "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground and stackover flow users")


    token := `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkNKc2hmNnhMOGVuODlhVVZVenJaX1JqMTJwS3pqZkFUdkNqcT    lNbUxGTlUifQ.eyJ2ZXIiO
jEsImp0aSI6IkFULlFxN21mck94RnhZaVFXZWpGQjczMTZnRXdQbWJBVGtsVzB6Sm1FWVRPU0UiLCJp    c3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Nvb
XBhbnl4Lm9rdGEuY29tL29hdXRoMi9hdXMxYTRpYmRhdDBKWXc1czFkOCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9s    b2NhbGhvc3Q6MzAwMCIsI
mlhdCI6MTQ4ODA2MDgxMywiZXhwIjoxNDg4MDY0NDEzLCJjaWQiOiIzam1OdlZDRlo1RjZsV096SU9O    TyIsInVpZCI6IjAwdTFhOXNrMXloenR3Y3FSMWQ4Iiwic2NwIjpbInJlYWQiLCJyZW1vdmUiLCJyZXN    lcnZlIl0sInN1YiI6InJlbW92ZUB3b3cuY29tIn0
.XFGZoVv-w4kRgqMDB-Me1RM1aO5f5JH8W_fLFGnYzkLXGassbKMWafAfVx9j-    wzaWVFfHtsH4fiLjZZbCRYkWli0b6Q3VjdDPJq
YcvhN_wQ9WTmqoJLNyY-    AA5o7yThL4Vz5ih7P_nJWMN7xEWUpWadeJbShvPNtdFHHPBFTAiDx0fXFs98vZHfeLEy2dnwYf4aY4p    w
jcfmhOZNaVahMtQh0dJVa0ai4KPMqQXDXMHDrbEwa2eWY_2pCPXUZekvC3DyRFeSfkRJ6fIe3d6XccDgAy_qzjBCjnutyezg7ZzV
d866wkb2j2kJwyr0w3Q5iBBFgxEv6vpcpaM_KHSXTyA`


// Spit the token to get the middle value xx.(we want this).xx



 fragments := strings.Split(token,".")
fmt.Println ( "Here is the value\n"+fragments[1])

jwtFragment, err := b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(fragments[1])
_=jwtFragment //

fmt.Println (err)

fmt.Println ("any ideas")
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT's are base64 URL encoded and not padded.

[Here's a fixed version on play](https://play.golang.org/p/LlRf2Pr5-0)

Only difference is I used [base64.RawURLEncoding](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#pkg-variables)